# How to get 2 points coordinates of a serie sharing same x value

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

**Short version:**
With dygraphs, I need to see the coordinates of points (of a unique serie) having same x. But dygraphs only show one of them.
Example:

```
P1=[1,2]
P2=[2,10]
P3=[2,12]
```

I want to be able to focus on P2 and see something like `P2, x=2, y=10` and have the corresponding for P3 if I focus on the latter.

Is there any way to do that ?

**Long version:**
In dygraphs library, I want to plot a time serie (TS) versus another one
That means for a specific time T1, TS1 has a value "A" and TS2 has a value "B".

I need to plot the point [A,B] corresponding to time "T1" in a chart with x-axis representing the TS1 values and y-axis representing TS2 ones.

My problem is for different times, I may have same values for TS1 or TS2.
The result is my "computed chart" has many points sharing the same "x".
Dygraphs allows to show only one of these points.
Is there any way to focus on each point having same x and see their coordinates ?

Comment: It sounds like you want a scatter chart, rather than a time series. dygraphs is much better-suited to rendering time series.

Comment: Dygraphs is a constraint to me. If i could, I would switch to another library. Is there any solution to my problem using Dygraphs ?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html) which traces out the scatter plot.

You may need to set `dateWindow` and `valueRange` explicitly since you're changing which series correspond to the x- and y-axes.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7113/) of what I mean:

```
new Dygraph(div,
    "T,X,Y\n" +
    "1,0,3\n" +
    "2,2,6\n" +
    ..., {
      plotter: function (e) {
        // This is the officially endorsed way to plot all the series at once.
        if (e.seriesIndex !== 0) return;
        var sets = e.allSeriesPoints;
        var ctx = e.drawingContext,
            g = e.dygraph;

        ctx.beginPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < sets[0].length; i++) {
          var x = sets[0][i].yval,
              y = sets[1][i].yval,
              coords = g.toDomCoords(x, y),
              screenX = coords[0],
              screenY = coords[1];
          if (i == 0) {
            ctx.moveTo(screenX, screenY);
          } else {
            ctx.lineTo(screenX, screenY);
          }
        }
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    });
```

As you can see from the demo, this renders correctly but would require some more work to get mouse interactions to look right.